# SharePoint Migration Tool - Full Control permission not preserved

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepointmigrationtool

I'm using SPMT version 3.2.118.0 and I'm trying to migrate a folder of a file share to the root folder a doclib of a SPO site while preserving permissions. Groups or users with Read and Write permissions are well migrated with these permissions preserved (read--read, write-->contribute) but groups or users with "full control" permissions are not migrated at all! And SPMT reports it has successfully migrated the content!

Example:

If my local share is C:\TestDocs with

- user1 having *Full control*
- group1 having *Read* perm
- group2 having *Write* perm
- group3 having *Full control*

The target /TestDocs document library of the SPO site will have indeed unique permissions but with:

- group1 having *Read* perm,
- group2 having *Contribute* perm

user1 and group3, which were supposed to have Full control permission, don't have any and have zero access to the doclib!

I checked the reports and logs but cannot find any information.

Any idea?

Thanks

Franck

Answer (score 0):

Franck, make sure you have synced the corresponding users and groups to Azure Active Directly before you do the migration.

According to the document: [File and folder permissions when using the SharePoint Migration Tool](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/understanding-permissions-when-migrating):

**Read**, **Write**, and **Full control** permissions will be migrated as long as users are mapped between on-premises and SPO. **Write** permission will be set to **Contribute** after migration while the other two will be reserved.

These are expected behaviors when using SPMT.

Just sync Active Directory accounts to AAD and run the tool again.

Comment: Well the AD users and AD groups are synced to AAD. And if I assigned a Read or Write permission to the user or group, the permission is preserved. As soon as the permission is Full Control on the file share, it's not preserved and lost (contrary to what is expected as described in the doc).

Comment: @frncks Ok I’ve tested with SPMT version 3.2.118.0 and reproduced this issue. So I download the Public preview version (3.4.119.0) and it migrated the files with full control permission successfully. Try this version: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/new-and-improved-features-in-the-sharepoint-migration-tool

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll give it a try.

Comment: I tested SPMT version 3.4.119.0 (public preview) and the issue is indeed solved. Thanks.

Comment: Did this problem re-occur with SharePoint Migration Tool v3.4.119.2? I recently upgraded to this version from 3.2, and any account with Full Control NTFS permissions doesn't show up while all others do. Yes, this domain account is synchronized to Azure AD using Azure AD Connect.